# Is it possible to still address the individual elements of an array via a pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am trying to write a program that will mutliply two numbers, but output the result in binary, showing the calculation (i.e. shifting the rows). I'm storing the binary numbers as an array of 32 characters, and each element is either 1 or 0.

I have a function that will convert decimal to binary character array, but then my array only exists within the function, but I need to use the array within another function and also within main. I was thinking it might be possible to use pointers to change the value of the array in main from within my converter function, so then the array will exist in main and can be used in other functions. Is this possible?

I've declared two pointers to character arrays:

```
char (*binOne)[32];
char (*binTwo)[32];
```

if I pass the pointer as a parameter to the function, can I still access each element? Sorry if I'm not making much sense here.

Comment: Show us the code. You could have a function like `void toBinary(char *buff, int num)` and then `char binary[32];` and `toBinary(binary, 9001)`.

Answer (score 2):

In C, most of the time array behaves like pointer to its first element, so what you probably want to do is:

```
void foo(char* arr){
  //some stuff, for example change 21-th element of array to be x
  arr[20] = 'x';
}

int main(){
  char binOne[32];
  char binTwo[32];

  // change array binOne
  binOne[20] = 'a';

  foo(binOne);

  // now binOne[20] = 'x'

  foo(binTwo);

  // now binTwo[20] = 'x'
}
```

Comment: So can I then use arr[1] etc within foo?

Comment: I mean, will arr[1], arr[2] etc refer to the first, second etc element in the array arr?

Comment: in C arr[0] is the first element, arr[1] is the second and so on.

Comment: A grudging +1. An array is *not* actually a pointer to its first element; rather, an array variable is implicitly *converted*, in many contexts, to such a pointer. Note that `sizeof(binOne)` will be at least `32`, while `sizeof(arr)` will be generally be `4` or `8`, depending on the platform.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I mean arr[0] first, arr[1] second etc. Thanks!

Comment: I've implemented this, and I just have garbage in my array. This is meant to change the values in the array in main from within the function, right?

Comment: @Alex: In C unless you explicitly set the values of a stack variable, it will be random.

Answer (score 1):

A continuation of what I added as a comment:

In C, if you want to modify/return an array, you'll do that by passing a pointer to it as an argument. For example:

```
int toBinary(char *buff, int num) { /* convert the int, return 1 on success */ }
...
char buff[32];
toBinary(buff, 9001);
```

In C, an array's name **is** it's address, it's the address of the first element:

```
buff == &buff == &buff[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. But you only need a pointer to the array not an array of pointers.
You need to prototype like
e.g.

```
void int_to_arr(int n, char *arr);
void arr_to_int(int *n, char *arr);

in main(){

   char *binarr = calloc(32, sizeof(char));
   int n = 42;
   int_to_arr(n, binarr);
}

void int_to_arr(int n, char *arr)
{
   //do you conversion
   //access array with 
   // arr[i]
}

void arr_to_int(int *n, char *arr)
{
   //do you conversion
   //access array with 
   // *n = result;

}
```